# Cannot get git to use merge tool

Tags: git

On Windows.

In my config, I have Beyond Compare set up:

```
$ git config --list | grep -i bc3
diff.tool=bc3
difftool.bc3.cmd="c:/program files (x86)/beyond compare 3/bcomp.exe" "$LOCAL" "$REMOTE"
difftool.bc3.path="c:/program files (x86)/beyond compare 3/bcomp.exe" "$LOCAL" "$REMOTE"
merge.tool=bc3
mergetool.bc3.cmd="c:/program files (x86)/beyond compare 3/bcomp.exe" "$LOCAL" "$REMOTE" "$BASE" "$MERGED"
mergetool.bc3.path="c:/program files (x86)/beyond compare 3/bcomp.exe" "$LOCAL" "$REMOTE" "$BASE" "$MERGED"
```

I can start Beyond Compare from the command line using that path.

But when there's a merge conflict in git, it's not used:

```
$ git rebase origin/qa
First, rewinding head to replay your work on top of it...
Applying: Krebs up top
Using index info to reconstruct a base tree...
M       file1.txt
.git/rebase-apply/patch:6: trailing whitespace.
Krebbs
warning: 1 line adds whitespace errors.
Falling back to patching base and 3-way merge...
Auto-merging file1.txt
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in file1.txt
error: Failed to merge in the changes.
Patch failed at 0001 Krebs up top
The copy of the patch that failed is found in: .git/rebase-apply/patch

When you have resolved this problem, run "git rebase --continue".
If you prefer to skip this patch, run "git rebase --skip" instead.
To check out the original branch and stop rebasing, run "git rebase --abort".
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

At a Windows command prompt enter the commands:

```
git config --global diff.tool bc3

# for version 4
git config --global difftool.bc3.path "c:/Program Files (x86)/Beyond Compare 4/bcomp.exe"

# for version 3
git config --global difftool.bc3.path "c:/Program Files (x86)/Beyond Compare 3/bcomp.exe"
```

**Note**:
Git versions older than `2.2.0` (git --version) use "bc3" as the keyword for BC4.
For `git 2.2.0+`, use `bc`.

To launch a diff using Beyond Compare, use the command `git difftool foofile.txt`.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to leave out the parameters at the end ? Also it seems that only the pro version supports 3 way merge.

Check out the instructions at [Beyond Compare Doc](http://www.scootersoftware.com/support.php?zz=kb_vcs#githubwindows) which suggests the following setup

> BC version 3
>
> Diff
>   At a Windows command prompt enter the commands:
>
> git config --global diff.tool bc3
>
> git config --global difftool.bc3.path "c:/Program Files (x86)/Beyond Compare 3/bcomp.exe"
>
> To launch a diff using Beyond Compare, use the command "git difftool foofile.txt".
>
> 3-way Merge Pro only
>
> At a Windows command prompt, enter the commands:
>
> git config --global merge.tool bc3
>
> git config --global mergetool.bc3.path "c:/Program Files (x86)/Beyond Compare 3/bcomp.exe"
>
> To launch a 3-way merge using Beyond Compare, use the command "git mergetool foofile.txt".

Comment: Yes, I did try those as well.  It's not being called.

Even if the parameters weren't quite correct, I'd expect Beyond Compare to at least come up and give me an error.  It's not coming up at all.

Comment: When you run    _git mergetool --tool-help_ does it show bc3 as a valid merge tool ?